# How to Resolve ASP.NET Dropdown history navigation issue

Tags: asp.net, navigation, history

I have the following web app: 
- one dropdown to change the days of the week
- one span that updates its inner text based on the above selection
- the dropdown is set to autopostback

My problem is that when navigating back and forward from the browser buttons the page is inconsistent. For instance: in its initial state the week day is 'Monday' both in the dropdown and the span. If i change to 'Tuesday' everything gets updated nicely but if I hit now the Back button then the span changes back to 'Monday' but the dropdown isn't.

[image]

Is there any way to tackle this cache issue?

Here is the simple web app:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>   

<asp:DropDownList ID="DaysCombo" runat="server"
        AutoPostBack = "true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DaysCombo_SelectedIndexChanged"            
        />    

<div runat="server">
    <span id="ContentSpan" runat="server"></span>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

and code-behind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] days = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
            this.DaysCombo.DataSource = days;
            Page.DataBind();
            this.ContentSpan.InnerText = days[0];
        }          

    }

    protected void DaysCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentSpan.InnerText = this.DaysCombo.SelectedValue;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using javascript on the client because it avoids having to post back to the server. You could add a javascript load and change listener to ensure the span text and drop down are in synch

Comment: This minimalistic example is only for presenting the problem, in reality instead of the span I have many server controls that are updated from code-behind.

Comment: The browser back button restores the page with all input fields populated with entered values. I guess you could disable browser caching so the page is always retrieved from the server, or you could use ASP.NET Ajax and wrap it all inside an UpdatePanel so the browser back button isn't enabled?

Comment: @Elz sorry, forgot to @ you in previous comment